# Size of Pipe from Expansion Tank to Hot Water Heater

Tags: plumbing

Is it ok to use 1 in. pipe from expansion tank to the hot water heater instead of 3/4 in. that is used for inlet and outlet pipes?  I think 1 in. may be better, but not sure.  One thing I have determined is better insofar as vertical mounting of the tank is that the psi check valve should be on top and water draining from the bottom, which means in most cases that the labels identifying the brand of tank and specs are upside down.  Otherwise, over a period of time the water may become stagnant and develop bacteria, so better to keep the water moving and kept fresh.

Comment: What size are the fittings on hot water heater and expansion tank?  If they are 3/4 also, that means you have to to add more fittings(reducers/expanders), adding more possibles of places to leak.  If the two fittings/holes are for 1 inch pipe, then go for it.  The less joints the less leaks possible.

Comment: Given the purpose of a thermal expansion tank, 1/4" would be fine. The function is not that of a pressure tank in a well system that needs rapid response. You also have some other misconceptions regarding how water in a pressurized system behaves. It goes in and out top or bottom exactly the same, because it's moving with changes in pressure, not by gravity. Keep it where it belongs on the cold feed (it doesn't even need to be close to the water heater, so long as there's no check valve), and have clean incoming water, if you are concerned with bacterial growth.